# C clarification on recursive functions

Tags: c, function, recursion

Hello getting better at C everyday, this is a example problem out of my textbook that generates fibonacci numbers and shows recursive functions. The program works but I just don't understand how... Specifically in parts `(looper % 5)`, the whole function`fib` and what `printf(", %8ld", fib(looper));` is doing. Is it like saying fib() do x amount of times. If this problem is not easy to explain then could someone show me a easier way to understand how recursive functions work other then "towers of hanoi" example. Thanks. 
NOTE: program is meant to handle up to 30 numbers others wise it starts to look ugly.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

long fib (long num);

int main(void)
{
    int seriesSize;

    printf("This program will print out a Fibonacci series.\n");
    printf("How many many numers do you wnat? ");

    scanf_s("%d", &seriesSize);

    printf("First %d Fib numbers: \n", seriesSize);
    for (int looper = 0; looper < seriesSize; looper++)
    {
        if (looper % 5)
        {
            printf(", %8ld", fib(looper));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n%8ld", fib(looper));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

long fib(long num)
{
    if (num == 0 || num == 1)
    {
        return num;
    }
    return (fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2));
}
```

Comment: `if (looper % 5)` just helps to format output, separating values using `","` or `"\n"`.

Comment: Oh looking back at the program I seen now that it just adds the "," on the four lines. i.e 1..4 % 5 = "," and 5 % 5 = 10.
% can be confusing sometimes....
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind the `long fib(long num)` function is that it mirrors the natural definition of the fibonacci sequence in that it is defined in terms of itself. That is, fib(n) is defined by fib(n-1) and fib(n-2). For example, fib(5) is fib(4)+fib(3).

The textbook has written the function in a recursive manner as described above. Note that this is not the most efficient way to implement a fibonacci function but it does logically make sense.

To understand it, it pays to trace through its execution with an example input. Take fib(3) for example. The first `if` statement doesn't trigger because `num` is not 0 or 1. Thus, it works out what fib(2) and fib(1) are, and adds them together. We know what fib(1) does - it returns 1 in the first if statement. Trace through fib(2) in a similar manner and you'll see that it returns 1. Thus, fib(3) will return fib(2)+fib(1)=2. You can extend this further - take fib(4). It will return fib(3)+fib(2), which we know are 2 and 1, hence fib(4) = 3.

This approach can be taken for most recursive functions - think of it as creating new instances of the fib() function which continually creates until it "bottoms out" at an end case (num == 1 or num == 0, in this case), and returns back up, filling in the answers until you get back to the function you started with, with the answer.

Comment: Ok, I now understand the math now of the fibonacci numbers. Thanks for that clarification in that. So in the fib() function how does the value of looper get into the function when it is long fib(long num). So functions in C are smart enough to just set looper = num? With out a pointer and different types to - because normally I would use pointers for something like this... Thats wonderful if that is the case. I wish my book would have more on the matter...

Comment: The prototype for the `fib` function takes one "argument", of type `long`, called `num`. In the code, it's called like: `fib(looper)`. This means that whatever the current value of looper is, it's passed into the `fib` function as the first argument and gets saved into `num`. Thus, when you interact with the value inside `fib()`, you just refer to the `num` variable. This means it doesn't matter what the name of the argument is in the code that calls `fib`, the variable will be placed into the `num` variable and you can use that. Handy!

Comment: That is fantastic! I was playing with functions to test this and yes it works indeed. Thank you for your help.